Why is the new generation usage at 81% with only about 10MB used, despite A 10GB max size, by map and application is experiencing frequent YG C
In the JVM configuration, the maximum space of the new generation is 10G, but the actual usage is only about 10M, and the usage rate reaches 81%. The application is undergoing frequent YGC. Why is this?
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.292-b10

using thread-local object allocation.
Parallel GC with 23 thread(s)

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio         = 0
   MaxHeapFreeRatio         = 100
   MaxHeapSize              = 32210157568 (30718.0MB)
   NewSize                  = 680525824 (649.0MB)
   MaxNewSize               = 10736369664 (10239.0MB)
   OldSize                  = 1362100224 (1299.0MB)
   NewRatio                 = 2
   SurvivorRatio            = 8
   MetaspaceSize            = 21807104 (20.796875MB)
   CompressedClassSpaceSize = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   MaxMetaspaceSize         = 17592186044415 MB
   G1HeapRegionSize         = 0 (0.0MB)

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 9961472 (9.5MB)
   used     = 8112088 (7.736289978027344MB)
   free     = 1849384 (1.7637100219726562MB)
   81.43463134765625% used
From Space:
   capacity = 3670016 (3.5MB)
   used     = 1589360 (1.5157318115234375MB)
   free     = 2080656 (1.9842681884765625MB)
   43.30662318638393% used
To Space:
   capacity = 3670016 (3.5MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 3670016 (3.5MB)
   0.0% used
PS Old Generation
   capacity = 270008320 (257.5MB)
   used     = 198744848 (189.53785705566406MB)
   free     = 71263472 (67.96214294433594MB)
   73.60693477889866% used

26587 interned Strings occupying 2503840 bytes.



GC INFO

  S0     S1     E      O      M     CCS    YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
  0.00  32.40  64.19  67.86  94.52  91.41  39253  374.907  1476  115.701  490.609
  0.00  32.40  64.27  67.86  94.52  91.41  39253  374.907  1476  115.701  490.609
  0.00  32.40  69.90  67.86  94.52  91.41  39253  374.907  1476  115.701  490.609
  0.00  32.40  72.39  67.86  94.52  91.41  39253  374.907  1476  115.701  490.609
  0.00  32.40  84.04  67.86  94.52  91.41  39253  374.907  1476  115.701  490.609
 50.00   0.00  86.05  67.93  94.52  91.41  39254  374.912  1476  115.701  490.614
 50.00   0.00  86.14  67.93  94.52  91.41  39254  374.912  1476  115.701  490.614
 50.00   0.00  90.17  67.93  94.52  91.41  39254  374.912  1476  115.701  490.614
  0.00  30.67  62.13  68.27  94.52  91.41  39255  374.917  1476  115.701  490.619
 67.94   0.00  41.23  68.37  94.52  91.41  39256  374.922  1476  115.701  490.623
 67.94   0.00  52.49  68.37  94.52  91.41  39256  374.922  1476  115.701  490.623
  0.00  46.51  44.64  68.67  94.52  91.41  39257  374.927  1476  115.701  490.628
  0.00  46.51  48.51  68.67  94.52  91.41  39257  374.927  1476  115.701  490.628
  0.00  46.51  54.30  68.67  94.52  91.41  39257  374.927  1476  115.701  490.628
  0.00  46.51  54.30  68.67  94.52  91.41  39257  374.927  1476  115.701  490.628

I checked the information and saw that some people said that the JVM will dynamically adjust according to the actual situation, but I am not sure why the actual behavior of the JVM is inconsistent with the configuration. Can anyone explain it?

Don't expect that everything is collected at each GC run.

Why is frequent young gen GC surprising, ever?

The 10 MB is enough for what your application is doing. Frequent GC of the young generation is not a problem. Why do you think it is?
